# How do I get the value in a generic Dictionary?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have a `json` string like this:

```
{
  "ipaddress": "xxx",
  "hostname": "comcast.xxx",
  "popup": {
    "position": "1256",
    "pagename": "home"
  }
}
```

In my Windows Form code I've been using `JavaScriptSerializer` for phare those line to dictionary.

```cs
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

It is working fine at the moment, but I don't know how to get value inside `popup`? Because it's another dictionary.

```cs
[7] = {[popup, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest (yet unsafe) way of doing it is like this is via the indexer:

First extract the first dictionary and cast, since the first dictionary will yield an object of type `object`:

```
var popup = (Dictionary<string, object>)obj["popup"];
```

Then, you extract the values based on keys:

```
var position = popup["position"];
var pagename = popup["pagename"];
```

If you're not sure both keys will exist in the result, you can use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` if they exist:

```
obj position;
if (!popup.TryGetValue("position", out position))
{
    // Key isn't in the dictionary.
}
```

Comment: It's error, `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'` I've tried at first but it isn't work.

Comment: This would need a cast as the compiler only knows it'll be an `object` and not an `IDictionary<string,object>`

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON .Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), then simply:

```
JObject dynJson = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

followed by:

```
string data = dynJson["popup"]["position"];
```

[JObject.Parse](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)

Comment: I've tried too but when I compress and obfuscator code, my application has stop working.

Comment: @vietnguyen09 so without the compress/obfuscator the above code does work for you?? :)

Comment: Yes, it's working fine with out obfuscator, it's very nice helper class